# Invalid Regular Expression` Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I'm trying to parse CSS file with this expression:

```
rulePatt = new RegExp("(?<=\\s)(?<!\\:\\s)#.*?\\{.*?\\}","gm");
```

It works in two different regex testers I used, but when I put it in the wild it generates javascript error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\s)(?<!\:\s)#.*?\{.*?\}/: Invalid group
```

Fiddle here to form a impression on what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/LoomyBear/44XtU/1/

I guess I miss something really important here.
Please help ...
Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript doesn't do look behinds.

Comment: All regular expression engines have their peculiarities. When working on a regex you should from the start work with the target language.

Comment: @Jack thanks! I guess you're right! any thoughts on how to make it work? I'm trying exclude entries which have `/:/s` in front of them

Comment: You need to give more context, like what you're trying to match and what you're doing with the expression.

Comment: @Jack I updated the question with the fiddle, please check! Thanks!!

Comment: It's still not entirely clear; which parts of the CSS in particular do you want to match? Things that start with an identifier?

Comment: I want to match selectors with containing id's `#top_header li a:hover  { ... }` or `#main_header { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern

```
var regex = /(?:^|[^:])\s(#[^{]*\{[^}]*\})/gm;
```

Your result is in the first capturing group.

explanations:

```
(?:^|[^:])   # begining of the line or a character that is not a :
\s           # a white space
(#
[^{]*        # all characters expect { zero or more times
\{
[^}]*        # all characters expect } zero or more times
\})
```

The first lookbehind `(?<=\s)` imposes a white space before the sharp, it s the reason why i wrote a \s before.
The second lookbehind `(?<!:\s)` forbids a `:` before this space, thus, at this position is only allowed nothing (ie: the begining of the line) or a character that is not a `:`

Comment: That doesn't look quite right; it would also help if you could explain how you converted the look behinds into this :)

Comment: Actually this kinda did the trick, thanx! I've used the parts of your explanation to compose a valid regex for me which is `#[^{';)(]*\{[^}]*\}` ... CHEERS!!

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic look-behinds in JavaScript by using memory groups, e.g.:

```
var patt1 = /(?:\}|$)\s*(#[^\{]+)/g,
    m;

while ((m = patt1.exec(parseStr)) !== null) {
    output += m[1] + '<br>';
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/44XtU/2/)

First you match either the start of the subject or the closing brace of the previous definition, followed by optional white space. The rest is more or less your original expression.

To iterate over each match you must use `RegExp.exec()` instead of `$.each()` so that you can choose which memory group to add to `output`.

Comment: This works well, but I can not understand how ))) Anyway thanks!

Comment: @LoomyBear but you understood your previous expression? :) I've only turned your negative look-behind into a regular match, i.e. only consider a # if preceded by either the start of your string or the closing curly brace of the previous CSS expression.